# How to run a JavaScript code after append them to a div

Tags: javascript, angular

the API return a html code and I need to run them after received

```
<div>
  <script src="https://test.com/checkoutcheckout.js" 
          data-error="error" data-cancel="cancel"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
       function error(error) { 
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
       }
       function cancel(){
         console.log("cancelled");
         alert("cancelled");
       }
  </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
      Checkout.configure(
          {session
             {id:"SESSION3753y73971y5451"}
          });
      Checkout.redirectToPage();
 </script>
</div>
```

my current code

```
this.renderer2.setProperty(document.getElementById("mpgsCard"), 
            'innerHTML', apiReturnedHtml);
```

But it seem not working. The code is appended to the div but did not execute successfully. How can I handle that issue?

Comment: Are you expecting these two data attributes `data-error="error" data-cancel="cancel"` to run as functions?

Comment: No, I want to trigger the function through Checkout.configure({session: {id: "SESSION3753y73971y5451"}}) and Checkout.redirectToPage()

Answer (score 1):

To working div first you need to create a div on the script code and paste it inside the HTML after creating you may create a time to let the function work after some time or you may type the respective code after appending the div.

Comment: I have tried to create a div through `createElement`, and place it to the `document.body`. And append the html code into that div. But still not working.